# WampServer: Forbidden from accessing localhost but phpMyAdmin still accessible?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I'm suddenly unable to access anything in my www directory.

`localhost`, `localhost/index.php` etc all give me a 403 Forbidden error, but I can access phpMyAdmin just fine.

I have tried the solutions found in previous questions regarding this issue, but changing my httpd.conf file to `Allow from All`, or `Allow from 127.0.0.1::01` etc hasn't made a difference. Trying to access the files through `127.0.0.1/index.php` instead of `localhost/index.php` doesn't work either.

I have checked to see that the server is Online, and have also tried restarting all services.

My entire Apache access log from today is as follows:

```
::1 - - [13/May/2014:13:46:05 +0100] "GET /www HTTP/1.1" 403 205
::1 - - [13/May/2014:13:46:09 +0100] "GET /www/ HTTP/1.1" 403 206
::1 - - [13/May/2014:13:47:52 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:48:00 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:51:43 +0100] "GET /old/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 215
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:51:43 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:52:02 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:52:02 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:52:38 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:52:38 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:52:39 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:52:39 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:52:40 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:52:40 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:53:38 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:53:38 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:53:39 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:53:39 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:53:40 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:53:40 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:53:53 +0100] "GET /originalnew/index.php HTTP/1.1" 403 223
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2014:13:53:53 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
::1 - - [13/May/2014:13:56:07 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
::1 - - [13/May/2014:13:56:07 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
::1 - - [13/May/2014:13:57:02 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202
::1 - - [13/May/2014:13:57:02 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 213
```

I'm running Windows 7, and I haven't personally made any changes to my firewall since I last used WampServer.

I appreciate any help you can give. Thanks.

Edit: My httpd.conf is as follows.

```
ServerRoot "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22"

Listen 80

LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/php5apache2_2.dll"

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>

User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin admin@localhost
ServerName localhost:80
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"

<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Click on the wamp icon from task bar (left click once) and then click on the menu item "Put Online"

Comment: Thanks, but that was the first thing I tried when I realised it wasn't working.

Comment: have you changed any of the apache or vhost configurations?

Comment: The only file I've changed was the httpd.conf, to try allowing access from all.

Comment: Show your httpd.conf. Especially the bit you modified.

Comment: Have added my httpd.conf to the OP - I modified the contents of the <directory> tags. Perhaps I'm missing a module that I should have loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Try:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You can read about ordering here: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/apache/ch05_06.htm

From what I can tell, you are essentially saying: process all allow directives first, then any deny directives. Then you have Allow from All, which is then counteracted by Deny from All. Switching the ordering to deny,allow should fix it, or just removing the Deny from All directive. I did not test though.